# How should I test JApplets and Applets?

Tags: java, swing, testing, applet, japplet

Been playing with Java for quite a while now, and I just started working with `JApplet`s/`Applet`s. The problem I'm having is actually testing them. As you all probably know, most browsers cache the files, so if you update any of your code, the `JApplet`s/`Applet`s don't refresh. I've read that you can change the name of the HTML file that hosts the `JApplet`/`Applet`, and thus "trick" the browser into caching a "new" program. This doesn't always seem to work unfortunately.

Another method I see quite often is using the command `appletviewer` in command line, but I've never been able to get this to work.

So I was wondering, how should I test my `JApplet`s/`Applet`s? What is the best way? How do you test your them?

Comment: *"and I just started working with `JApplet`s/`Applet`s."*  Don't - if you need a rich client to consume a web app., code a `JFrame` and launch it using JWS.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Can't agree more with the above comments. Not only is JWS better than Applets, but they are both rapidly falling out of user favor with all of the recent exploits

Comment: @AndrewThompson, that page was very insightful. Thank you. JWS is Java Web Start correct? So you think that it would be better to "launch" a `JFrame` instead of making a useless applet? I might just start using Javascript or something. It seems a whole lot easier for a web based app.

Comment: *"JWS is Java Web Start correct?"*  Correct.  *"So you think that it would be better to "launch" a JFrame instead of making a useless applet?"*  Yes. *"I might just start using Javascript or something. It seems a whole lot easier for a web based app."*  Good call.  Personally I prefer the desktop 'rich client' (frame/JWS) but often such a desktop app. will bring too little to the web-app. (that can't be done using AJAX, jQuery & HTML 5).

Comment: Alright, well thank you for taking the time to give all the insight and advice. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Applet Testing

#### 1. The appletviewer

The appletviewer is relatively easy to use.  Here is the example from the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).

```
/* <!-- Defines the applet element used by the appletviewer. -->
<applet code='HelloWorld' width='200' height='100'></applet> */
import javax.swing.*;

/** An 'Hello World' Swing based applet.

To compile and launch:
prompt> javac HelloWorld.java
prompt> appletviewer HelloWorld.java  */
public class HelloWorld extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        // Swing operations need to be performed on the EDT.
        // The Runnable/invokeLater() ensures that happens.
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // the crux of this simple applet
                getContentPane().add( new JLabel("Hello World!") );
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(r);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Appleteer

The [Appleteer - applet test tool](http://pscode.org/appleteer/) was designed by me to provide more feedback on an applet launch or the reasons for failure.  Main features:

- Loads applet web pages in an applet enabled JEditorPane.
- Supports multiple applets on the same page, along with applet communication/object sharing & the 1.4+ InputStream sharing mechanism.
- Supports the applet showDocument()/showStatus methods.
- **Helps avoid applet class caching.**
- Allows inspection of

  1. The getAppletInfo() & getParameterInfo() defined for the applet.
  2. Parameters requested by applet code. Very handy for poorly documented applets!
- Can provide easy access to the following information.

  1. Split output and error streams,
  2. Has in-built logging, and all applet logs to the anonymous logger are added to the main log. Along with easy configuration of..

     - Log level.
     - Log history length.
  3. Applet lifecycle Throwables logged.